# How to get size of HttpPostedFileBase file

Tags: asp.net

I have a function that has a parameter of type **HttpPostedFileBase** and I'm getting the file's name using (Path.GetFileName):

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
       {
           foreach (var file in attachments)
           {

               var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
}
}
```

How can I get the file size??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `ContentLength` property on the `HttpPostedFileBase` class contains the number of bytes in the posted file

```
int byteCount = file.ContentLength;
```

See this link for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.contentlength.aspx